# Magnetic field distribution near the outside surface region of wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

According to Biot-Savart Law， we can calculate the magnetic field distribution generated by a stationary electric current.

However, I am wondering how to calculate the field at points near the surface region of the wire powered with current.

(P.S. As my personal consideration, the magnetic field magnitude can be infinity in those points.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the magnetic field value to be infinite, you would have to have a wire with a radius of zero (no such thing exists, even a focused stream of pure electrons would have a radius greater than zero). You would probably get a good approximation by plugging the radius of the wire into the formula. The point being that you use the distance to the center of the wire, not to the surface of the wire, when calculating magnetic field strength.

Comment: I am so appreciated for your help. Actually, I want to canculcated a field caused by iron-core solenoid electromagnet powered with a stationary electric current. I divided this question into two parts. First, I will calculate the field generated using air-core solenoid; Second， I will caculate the magnetization of the iron-core within such a field, namelly F1.Third, I will caculate the magentic field generated by the magnetized iron-cor,namelly F2. Fourth, I will sum F1 and F2 to get the results.

Comment: So, I must take the detailed distribution of magentic field near the soleniod into accout.

Comment: I am totally understand what you pointed out. The radius of course should be take into account. But, it seems that I am still wondering the field's strength is too strong to be accuratelly calculated such easy.

Comment: Besides，as the strength is to strong, the iron-core in such region seems always be saturated. I cant believe this results.